# grpc server immediately quits if running together with treaded Flask app

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying to run Flask REST API and gRPC API inside a single application and container, and for some reason gRPC server closes immediately after start.

So I have a simple Flask app that is serving few REST endpoints. It has two blueprints and bootstraps with pretty standard entrypoint:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from app import bootstrap

app_name = os.environ.get(C.KEYS.APP_NAME_KEY)
conf_data = bootstrap.get_conf_data(app_name)
flask_app = bootstrap.get_app(app_name, conf_data)
bootstrap.register_blueprints(flask_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run()
```

I've created a separate module that implements a simple gRPC interface, and I want to run both concurrently on different ports inside the same application and container. Default gRPC server implementation uses `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and is nonblocking, so I assume it should be able to run in the background of Flask app execution. gRPC server bootstrap looks like this:

```
import grpc
from concurrent import futures

from svc.auth_grpc import auth_pb2, auth_pb2_grpc


def start_server():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1),
                         maximum_concurrent_rpcs=1)
    auth_pb2_grpc.add_AuthServiceServicer_to_server(AuthServiceServicer(),
                                                    server)
    server.add_insecure_port(f'0.0.0.0:9091')
    server.start()
```

And since my goal is to make gRPC and Flask coexist - I'm adding gRPC bootstrap to the application entrypoint like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
    flask_app.run()
```

I expect that gRPC will start a thread and live in background indefinitely, while Flask will execute standard blocking werkzeug bootstrap and will live in foreground. All of this happens at the start, however the next second after Flask start the gRPC queue `CompletionQueue` receives a `SHUTDOWN` event and server quits.

I don't know why this event happens and what triggers it, and I cannot dig deeper into the `CompletionQueue` because it's Cython implementation underneath.

Separately gRPC server and Flask app run correctly with all the rest of code unchanged.

How do I make these two event loops coexist?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `server` variable will be garbage collected after the `start_server` function finishes. That's why the gRPC server seems closed immediately. To solve this problem, you can use a global variable to store the server object.

Also, if you think this API design is not ideal, feel free to submit an issue on the GitHub repo https://github.com/grpc/grpc.